# how to use substring in linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting one exception while using a substring with lastindex of, 
  exception is given below

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 LastIndexOf(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

my db stored file name format is like this C:\Data\MyFileName.xml
and I am passing the name of the file to find out specific record

```
filename = MyFileName.xml

var record = (from fd in db.Details
where (fd.FullName.Substring(fd.FileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1)) == fileName
                          select fd).First();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, [`LastIndexOf` method is not mapped in LINQ to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

But, I think `EndsWith` can make it for your case:

```
where fd.FileName.EndsWith(fileName)
```

or to make it better, concatenate `fileName` with `@"\"`:

```
where fd.FileName.EndsWith(@"\" + fileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I know that there are certain C# functions which cannot be used in a Linq query, even if they show up in your editor.  I believe the reason is that it gets translated to SQL which does not have a way of implementing them.  I would try selecting the entire name (the first one) and then doing the substring function *after* the query.

Comment: Yeah, get the entire table into memory and perform query as LINQ to Objects. That's really not a good idea :)